# How can I make the render camera follow my mouse navigation?

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, camera, navigation

I have a big scene, I want to render many different shots from various angles, is there a way to make the camera to render exactly what I’m looking at in the view port?
I want the camera to follow my mouse movement wherever I go and render what I am seeing without having to switch between cameras.

Comment: There is a "Lock camera to view" toggle in the View panel, could it achieve what you want to do ? You need to be in camera view first with numpad 0

Comment: Indeed! Thank you! this solves the problem, the menu was hidden so I couldn't find where the toggle is... Turned out there's a teeny tiny hidden shelf hidden in the upper right corner of the viewport, once you slide it open, you can access the view properties... Thanks again :)

Comment: Yes ! Alternatively you can toggle it on/off with the shorctut "N". Similarly you can toggle the left side panels with the shortcut "T". You will use these a lot in Blender !